# Using templates in struct -- to make a generic linked list

Tags: c++, templates, struct, linked-list

In .NET I really liked System.Generic.List and wanted to replicate it as a way of learning the C++ language. The problem is that I want it to be generic, I want the elements to contain a value of a template type T. I know most of what to do, but the problem lies within the node.

```
template<class T>
struct node
{
    T value;
    bool isFirst;
    node *next;
};
```

I have tried googling this for a while and haven't found anything relevant. I have just gone through the tutorials at www.cplusplus.com. Do I have to reference the class here with a pointer, if so, how?

Thanks in advance

Gisle Aune

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: The error isn't in your type definition. It must be in node declarations.

Comment: What`s your problem? Please be more specific (doesn´t the code compile, do you fail to instantiate node-instances, etc).

Comment: An introductory C++ textbook should cover liked lists. I recommend that you borrow a book from your local university or public library.

Comment: Thanks, I want it as an exercise mostly to learn linked lists. Thanks to you, I found the error, I wasn't reffering to node with the <T> in other places in the code. (sorry for writing a comment in the answer field, using an extremely bad network connection and the "add comment" field doesn't seem to appear here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Actually, I would probably write it as

```
template<class T>
struct node
{
    T value;
    bool isFirst;
    node<T> *next;
};
```

because it's not much more verbose and it's clearer that `next` points to a `node` of the same type, but nevertheless also your version is fine: in a template, when you use the name of the class without explicitly specifying the template parameters, it's implied that they are the same ones of the template being currently instantiated. This is explained at §14.6.1 of the C++ standard:

> Within the scope of a class template, when the name of the template is neither qualified nor followed by <, it is equivalent to the name of the template followed by the template-parameters enclosed in <>. [Example: the constructor for `Set` can be referred to as `Set()` or `Set<T>()`. ] Other specializations (14.7.3) of
>   the class can be referred to by explicitly qualifying the template name with the appropriate template-arguments. [Example:

```
template<class T> class X {
    X* p;      // meaning X<T>
    X<T>* p2;
    X<int>* p3;
};
```

> —end example]

---

By the way, writing a generic list is a useful exercise to learn the language, but keep in mind that many generic containers are already available in the C++ standard library; besides the fact that they are throughly tested and optimized, their "iterators" abstraction allow you to use on almost any container the freestanding algorithms available in the library.

Answer (score 3):

this code is correctly written. Anyway, if you want to use generic lists in c++, you could use stl

```
#include <list>
std::list<int> lista;
```